# How to send file over socket after being written?

Tags: java, file, sockets

After a user fills in a form with TextAreas, I write the input into a .txt file.

Now how do I send it over to another computer of whose network i am connected with. I used a static IP for my PC and he has a static IP as well.

Any idea how I would send said txt file over? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If both computers are using Windows, using shared folder can be the easiest way to transfer the files. In the other computer, share a folder. Then you can actually write the file directly into the remote folder by specifying the file name as "\\SERVERNAME\FOLDERNAME\FILENAME".

If you really need to write to local disk first, then copy it to that shared folder you can do this:
If you use Java 7, use: java.nio.file.Files.move(). If you use Java 6 or older, you will need to use java.io.File.renameTo(), or via read and write operations.